# How to install Linux mint like menu/gnomenu in Ubuntu? 

Tags: menu, desktop-environments, mate

How to get the Linux mint menu or gnomenu / or something like it and install it through PPAs I don't want to use the tar.gz or .deb files to install it please help me (ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: It's my question, form a long time ago.  It's really to board, and to a EOL release, and the answer is form a user that don't exist anymore.  I can't delete it.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjIKA.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Linux Mint:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-nightly
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

For old GNOME:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

For Mate:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://packages.mate-desktop.org/repo/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main"  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install mate-archive-keyring mate-core mate-desktop-environment
```

Comment: For Mate D.E. Menu I want a windows like menu for mate